# Does putting warning on Cigarette packs reduce consumption?

Tags: marketing, smoking

Cigarette packs in various countries contain warnings on them, some of them contain only text, some contain text and pictures that suppose to ditter the user, and the most extreme are [Australian packs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cigarette_packets_in_Australia) that not only contain text warning and pictures, but also removed all branding from the packets.

Have any of those methods was proven to **reduce** smoking?

Some examples (I've blurred the brands from the pictures)

Just textual warning:

[image]

Australian pack:

[image]

Some anecdotal data:

I knew some (male) people in the army who wouldn't buy pacs that have an impotency warning on them, they would ask the salesperson for another pack. But they said that they would smoke cigarettes from such a pack, and if no other pack was available, they would buy it. So it didn't seem to discourage them from smoking.